# Installation requirements checklist in Landscap openstack

Tags: openstack-autopilot

Installation requirements checklist in Landscap openstack is grayed out. Ping is fine between maas and landscape. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Please check the job-handler.log file in the landscape server under /var/log/landscape-server, it might have some clues.